# Handling incoming calls in Android

Tags: android, phone-call

I want to handle incoming call in Android.
Actually I want to set a time duration in which if my cell phone receive any call then automatically a message send to each of them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just extend your class to `PhoneStateListener` and override `onCallStateChanged` method. Sample code:

```
class myCallListener extends PhoneStateListener{

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    // your logic here
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the response. but it not working for me.first i run code on device then call on device i got nothing instead of simple incoming call. please help me. how can i get it run.

Comment: Hi Sunit you need to add READ_PHONE_STATE in your manifest.xml and hope  you have done some logic so that you will be acknowledged when the piece of code gets executed...

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `PhoneStateListener` in your `Activity` or `Service`:

```
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
            ....
        } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
            ....
        } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
            ....
        }
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
};
```

And add following permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Hope this helps.