# Where to invoke a notification dialog box in a program with two classes

Tags: android, dialog

I am new in Android and I want to show the notification dialogbox when the call comes. I have 2 Java files:

1. `walkitalki`
2. `incomingcall`

The Java file `incomingcall` is called from `walkitalki`. I want a dialog box when the call comes.

I can't use `Toast` in the `incomingcall` java file because it is called from `walkitalki`. How would I display this notification dialog box, and in which Java file will it go?

Answer (score 0):

These two look like something you're looking for:

[Handling incoming call in android programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716481/handling-incoming-call-in-android-programming)

[Android: Presenting a notification during a call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427017/android-presenting-a-notification-during-a-call)

Although, from the looks of your question you may want to start with something simpler at this point, like accomplishing all of the android tutorials.